# How to save new localization of dragged marker?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I used example from:[Google-Maps-for-Rails-Marker-dragging](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Marker-dragging)

I have a page view, created by scaffolding. How to get from JavaScript and save a new position to the database as:  address, longitude, latitude after I click save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a listener to your marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() { 
    var latitude = marker.getPosition().lat();
    var longitude = marker.getPosition().lng();
    // use Ajax to save latitude, longitude  in the database
}
```